# sklearn Perceptron not able to classify NAND function

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, perceptron

I am new to Machine learning. I was implementing a Perceptron to see which logic gate functions are linearly separable. For NAND gate, I got unexpected result . For inputs X and output y, the model gives a score of 0.5 , and y prediction is [1,0,0,0] instead of [1,1,1,0]. Can anyone help me with whats wrong with my model

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron

clf = Perceptron(max_iter=100, random_state=0)

X= np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
y = np.array([1,1,1,0])
clf.fit(X, y)
score= clf.score(X, y)
print(score)
a=clf.predict(X)
print(a)
```

I am getting this output for the code

```
0.5
[1 0 0 0]
```

I tried calculating z (net input) from the weights and bias of the model like this:

```
w = clf.coef_ ;b = clf.intercept_
z= np.dot(X,w.T) +b
print(z.T)
```

which gave me the following result:

```
[[ 2.  0.  0. -2.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

It will iteratively converge, so the low accuracy might be because its not getting enough samples. You can give it more examples as follows:

```
X= np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]] * 2)
y = np.array([1,1,1,0] * 2)
```

This will duplicate your original examples twice.

Regarding your second point about the matrix operation - the perceptron has a step function at the very end that maps negative numbers to 0, and positive numbers to 1. After you perform the matrix operation, push it through a step function (`np.where` helps), and you should get the same classification output as the perceptron: `manual_predict = np.where(X @ w.T + b < 0, 0, 1)`.

Comment: I have even used max_iter=10,000 . Still the score is 0.5 . For other functions like AND (y= [0,0,0,1] ) and OR (y=[0,1,1,1] ) , the function is giving score of 1 (100% accuracy) with 100 iterations only

Comment: Try `X= np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]] * 2)` and `y = np.array([1,1,1,0] * 2)`. Notice I have added a `*2` to both `X` and `y`. This gives it more training examples (twice as much in this case). I get 100% accuracy with this. `max_iter` just sets the maximum *allowed* number of iterations (not the actual number of iterations).

Comment: I tried using X= np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]] * 2) and y = np.array([1,1,1,0] * 2). I am getting score=1. But clf.predict(X) gives [1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0]. Is the problem not changed. Because ouput array size is not same (4 vs 8 )

Comment: The `*2` *duplicates* the input list - the inputs are now 8. That's why the output is 8. The output looks right to me. `1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0` is correct for NAND of `00 01 10 11 00 01 10 11`.